# TinyMCE .NET dll could not be found

Tags: asp.net, security, .net-4.0, tinymce

I am trying to include the .Net TinyMCE dll in my project.  The code I am using is:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Moxiecode.TinyMCE" Namespace="Moxiecode.TinyMCE.Web" tagprefix="tinymce" %>
```

I have already added the dll to the references in the project and I checked the code in my csproj to make sure it is correct.  I modified it to make sure it had a path hint.

```
<Reference Include="Moxiecode.TinyMCE, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>bin\Moxiecode.TinyMCE.dll</HintPath>
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
</Reference>
```

When I try to build my project I receive the error message:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:[ProjectPath]\bin\Moxiecode.TinyMCE.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. Operation
>   is not supported. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80131515)

How to I resolve this error?  I have tried opening and closing VS2010.  Adding and dropping the reference.  Nothing has worked.

---

After more research it appears the issue is that I am using .Net 4.0 and TinyMCE's .Net dll does not have a Strong Name. Basically, it does not have a PublicKeyToken. How do I resolve this?

Comment: I've edited my answer with an updated reponse to your SNK query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will solve the problem but for your hint path to be relative, I believe you need to start it with `.\` (or `..\` for parent)

Where is the actual path to the DLL? Have you tried setting the build output level to Diagnostic (`Tools -> Options... -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run`)

Does that give you any more information?

For testing purposes, try creating a `C:\Bin\Moxiecode` and place the DLL in it. Does this fix the issue? (in which case it's a path problem). If not, it may be something else which is throwing a misleading exception (corrupt dll or similar?). [**Edit:** The path mentioned in this para was correct before the Q was edited]

Update: If you have a project being compiled with a strong name, all your references must have one also. This is to ensure that your code doesn't have something malicious injected into it. Your only options are:

- Don't strongly sign your project [Bad]
- Recompile the offending DLL yourself with an SNK [Good if you can get the source]
- Get the developers of the DLL to build you one with an SNK [Good if you can get it to happen]

Comment: My other reference paths are exactly the same and work without issue.  I tried putting the dll in `C:\Bin\Moxiecode.TinyMCE.dll` and that did not work.

Comment: I did built it in diagnostic mode and I got an error like this `An attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location which would have caused the assembly to be sandboxed in previous versions of the .NET Framework. This release of the .NET Framework does not enable CAS policy by default, so this load may be dangerous. If this load is not intended to sandbox the assembly, please enable the loadFromRemoteSources switch.` Then it referenced this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409252%28VS.100%29.aspx. Thing is, the document is local.

Comment: Interesting. The File:// syntax when used in browsers can reference UNC paths but I'm not sure about its use here. For testing purposes, can you try creating a new project with just a reference to that DLL and compile it - Does this fail also? Incidentally, when you downloaded the DLL, is there any chance it still has the unsafe download flag set? Depends on what OS you're using but Right-Click Properties and look @ General tab and also under advanced button.

Comment: It was marked as blocked!  I am using Windows 7.  The code for TinyMCE also came with it so I was able to recompile it with a SNK and that solved it was well.

Comment: @RandomBen Glad we solved it - I've never had the blocked problem with a DLL before but it's caught me out on other file types :)